# Why does the setter function in es6 return a celsius value instead of a farenheit value

Tags: es6-class

My question is about the setter function in the function makeClass().

```
set temperature(celsius) {
this.farenheit = celsius * 9.0 / 5 + 32;
}
```

1. Why does the code use the calculation F=C*9.0/5+32 which is the formula for farenheit and return 26 celsius instead of 26 farenheit as seen in the following part of the code that's outside the makeClass() function.

   temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in C

Below is the exercise from freecodecamp and it is correct but I don't actually understand how it works for the above reason.

```
function makeClass() {
  "use strict";
  /* Alter code below this line */
  class Thermostat {
    constructor(farenheit) {
      this.farenheit = farenheit;
    }
    get temperature() {
      return 5 / 9 * (this.farenheit - 32);
    }
    set temperature(celsius) {
      this.farenheit = celsius * 9.0 / 5 + 32;
    }
  }
  /* Alter code above this line */
  return Thermostat;
}
const Thermostat = makeClass();
const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in C
console.log(temp)
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in C
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: Because the getter returns celsius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor expects you to pass it a value in fahrenheit and it stores that value as fahrenheit.

The getter is programmed to return a value in celsius so since the value was previously stored in fahrenheit, it has to convert the stored value to celsius.

The setter is programmed to accept a value in celsius, but store it in fahrenheit so it has to convert the value that was passed to fahrenheit.

---

I have no idea why the constructor was programmed to accept a value in fahrenheit, but the getter and setter deal in celsius.  You'd have to ask the designer of this code why they did that.  My guess is that it's just for demo purposes to show you how you could have a getter/setter that automatically handle unit conversions for you.

Answer (score 0):

26 is passed into the parameter celsius in the setter function and converted into farenheit the result is passed into this.farenheit in the getter function and converted into celsius and returns 26 C when it's called outside the function.